# POST request doesn't always return full payload

Tags: .net, angular

I have a .NET/Angular application that consumes and produces to Kafka. When I do a POST request to add a new item, sometimes the new item will appear on the web page without having to do a full browser refresh. Other times we need to refresh the browser to see the new item.

Would this have anything to do with consumer latency on kafka, or are we more likely to be not handling something correctly on the .NET or Angular side as far as async operations go?

Here's some code on the Angular side:

```
        this.dialogService.wait('This may take a few seconds...', 'Creating Item');
        const item= this.createItemObject($event);
        this.itemervice
            .createitem(item)
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
                catchError(error => {
                    this.dialogService.dialogRef.close();
                    if (error.status === 409) {
                        this.sb.open('Duplicate item name. Please enter a unique name.', 'OK', this.snackbarConfig);
                        return error;
                    }
                })
            )
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.dialogService.dialogRef.close();
                this.dialogRef.close('success');
            });
    }

    createItemObject(ItemForm: FormGroup): Item {
        const item: Item = {
            id: 0,
            guid: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
            name: itemForm.get('name').value,
            active: itemForm.get('active').value
        };
        return item;
    }
 getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl).pipe(
            map((response: Item[]) => {
                return response;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

And the method that the above calls:

```
createItem(newItem: Item): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl, newItem).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Backend:

```
public async Task UpdateOrInsertItem(kafka.ItemUpdated itemUpdated, Guid guid)
        {
            var existingItem = await this.context.Items.FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.Guid == guid);
            var newItemId = 0;

            if (existingItem == null)
            {
                var newItem = new Item();
                newItem.Update(itemUpdated);
                newItem.Guid = guid;
                this.context.Items.Add(newItem);
                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
                newItemId = newItem.Id;
            }

            if (existingItem != null)
            {
                existingItem.Update(itemUpdated);
                await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            await this.AddAuditHistory(newItemId, itemUpdated.UserName, newItemId != 0);
        }
```

Code that updates the UI:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getItems();
    }

    getItems() {
        this.itemTemplate = this.itemService.getItems();
    }

    newItem() {
        this.dialog
            .open(ItemTemplateCreationComponent)
            .afterClosed()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response) {
                    this.getItems();
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please share code as a [mcve]

Comment: I just added some code on the front-end. Let me know if you'd like to see anything else

Comment: Your issue is related to Kafka, yes? So you should show your backend code as well

Comment: _not handling something correctly on the .NET or Angular side_ - That depends on how you display data. Are you polling the API, or are you using WebSockets/SSE?

Comment: Yes we're polling the API. I added another edit with probably the most relevant section of the back-end, let me know if you're looking for something more specific.

Comment: Still not seeing any part of this code that updates a UI, with respect to your HTTP client actions (you pipe to catch an error, but no response is returned there)

Comment: Ok, I added in the code that I believe edits the UI. Sorry, I don't have too much experience in Angular!

Comment: Removed Kafka tag since I still don't see any Kafka related code, telling me that it's just problems with your async/await logic... So, you have code `if (response)`, and no logging if you didn't get a response? What happens if there's some error there in `newItem()`?